# Autocompletion for my shell function, using oh-my-zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh, tab-completion, zsh-completion

I have a shell function that lets me quickly cd to a project:

```
p() {
  cd "$HOME/projects/$1"
}
```

However, it isn't very useful without autocomplete. I'm using oh-my-zsh, any idea how best to add oh-my-zsh's standard `cd` autocomplete to my function `p`?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck

Comment: Hey @shellter , from the [on topic article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), it seems to me that questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are appropriate for Stack Overflow.  This question is about oh-my-zsh, which is a common software tool for programmers, and there's tonnes of questions about oh-my-zsh on Stack Overflow. To me this seems like the most relevant Stack Exchange site to post this question on?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I suggest two cool plugins, both add some amazing features that will blow your mind.

1. https://github.com/clvv/fasd
2. https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions

Comment: Cool, thanks @SergioAraujo . Not the way I was thinking about solving the problem, but I'll give them a shot, both look like promising ways to super-quickly cd to the directories I want.